# HTTP caching in safari -- does it work?

Tags: http, safari, browser-cache

It seems to me that Safari doesn't use cache at all :-(

Max-age is set to at least one month, Cache-Control: is public, content is served over HTTPS. It seems that Safari doesn't use memory nor disk caching. Is there something like about:cache for Safari? (about:cache works in Firefox) Does your Safari use HTTP caching for content served over HTTPS?

Answer (score 1):

No, it is not working now (tested with Safari 3.2, 4.0 - Mac/Win).

Header "Cache-Control: public, max-age=999999" used over SSL (HTTPS) is causing that encrypted pages can be cached by browser.

This "feature" works well in Firefox 3.0+, IE6+ (tested with Firefox 3.0, 3.5; IE6, IE7, IE8).

But be aware, that caching content over HTTPS is not secure issue. Use this clever cache only for static files - it means JS, CSS and images (png, jpg, ...)!

Answer (score 0):

I was under the impression that all the browsers do NOT cache HTTPS. I thought it was a security/privacy feature.

Comment: IE does, and Firefox 3.5 does too, if you set Cache-Control to public. Safari doesn't ... or I just don't know correct headers to set :-(

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/174348/will-web-browsers-cache-content-over-https